# TFS 2010 Data Tier Configuration Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, tfs, installation

I am installing TFS2010. There is a separate Application Tier server and Database Tier server. I am using an already existing database, called Tfs_Configuration. When entering the database name/instance name I am able to test it and obtain the green check-mark so TFS can find the database. The version of SQL server I am connecting to is - SQL Server 2008 SP3. But when I run the readiness tests I get the following messages- 
[image]

First are those two warning causing the error?

Also, I have db_owner rights to the existing database (Tfs_Configuration) that I am connecting to. What other rights do I need? And what can I do to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

The first error suggests you need the sysadmin role which is in fact a SQL Server role which can be enabled by doing the following:http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/27/sql-server-add-any-user-to-sysadmin-role-add-users-to-system-roles/

Hope that moves you past at least one error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be Sysadmin of the SQL instance or a role that is able to create new databases, because the installer wants to create an additional database for the DefaultCollection (and the TFS_Warehouse, TFS_Analysis). Therefore it is not enough to be the owner of TFS_Configuration.

Comment: If I am not using either Reporting or Analysis services does TFS still create a Database? And if so, if they are created and I am db_owner of both will that suffice. (They will not allow TFS to create any databases if at all possible)

Comment: While running this as well I chose to not create a Team Project Collection at this time and create it later on via the Admin Console.

Comment: The installer will also attempt to setup the TFS Service account you specify with the proper DB permissions.  The account you run the installer as needs proper permissions to be able to do that in SQL.